# Expand MSBuild Properties containing wildcard into Items

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I am trying to write MSBuild script that will perform some action (eg. print its path) on an arbitrary files (specified as a property on a command line) in some predefined directory (F:\Files).

Given the following directory structure

```
F:\Files\TextFile.txt
F:\Files\Subdir1\ImageFile.bmp
F:\Files\Subdir1\SubSubdir\ImageFile2.bmp
F:\Files\Subdir1\SubSubdir\TextFile2.txt
```

And MSBuild Script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="PrintNames" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetDir>F:\Files</TargetDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Files Include="$(TargetDir)\$(InputFiles)"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="PrintNames">
        <Message Text="Files: @(Files, ', ')" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

running the script with InputFiles set to "**\*.bmp;**\*.txt" works fine only for bmp files. Txt files are taken from the current working directory, not from "F:\Files"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems that you have to solve:

1. $(InputFiles) is specifed as a scalar property, but you want to interprete it as an array
2. $(InputFiles) contains wildcards you want to expand *after* you do transformation on the list of patterns in $(InputFiles).

It is easy to solve either of two problems separately, but combination of the two is actually tricky. I have one possible solution, and it works, but the downside is you have to encode '*' characters in your pattern definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="PrintNames" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"> 
  <PropertyGroup> 
    <TargetDir>c:\temp\MyContent</TargetDir> 
    <InputFilesRelativeEsc>%2A%2A\%2A.bmp;%2A%2A\%2A.txt</InputFilesRelativeEsc>
  </PropertyGroup> 

  <Target Name="PrintNames"> 
    <ItemGroup>
        <_TempGroup Include="$(InputFilesRelativeEsc)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <CreateItem Include="@(_TempGroup->'$(TargetDir)\%(Identity)')"> 
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="_EvaluatedGroup" /> 
    </CreateItem> 
    <Message Text="_EvaluatedGroup: %(_EvaluatedGroup.FullPath)" />

  </Target> 
</Project>
```

It works as follows. Property `InputFilesRelativeEsc` is a list of relative file patterns. Notice wildcard characters are encoded (%2A is a hex code for asterisk). Since the wildcards encoded, the group `_TempGroup` does not attempt to search for and extract list of files while you `Include` this patterns into this group. Now `_TempGroup` is a group which consists of two elements: `**\*.bmp` and `**\*.txt`. Now that you have a real group you can transform it. The only complication is that the normal MSBuild mechanism of running transform does not expand wildcards. You have to use older `CreateItem` task. The `CreateItem` task is actually declared deprecated by MSBuild team, but it still works.

Comment: Looks like it's the only way (without implementing custom task), thanks. I tried using Property functions (.Replace("%", "%2A")) to avoid the necessity of passing an escaped property, but it did not work.

Comment: Just lovely, and yes: confirming that the CreateItem task *does* expand the wildcard escaped in a Property this way, whereas creating the ItemGroup inline in an <ItemGroup> doesn't work.

Comment: How could I use this to output <EmbbededResource><Link/></EmbeddedResource> items?